# Load testing with Jmeter and selenium plugin

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm looking to perform a browser based load test on my application. I was looking this option to use selenium plugin with Jmeter. So that I can write the required UI flow with Selenium within Jmeter and parameterize using Jmeter options.

I've used Jmeter for http/https request with 400/500 concurrent users.

Is it possible to use Jmeter + Selenium plugin for a browser level load test with around 400/500 concurrent users?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically yes but you will need to think about the hardware.

As per [Firefox 102 System Requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/102.0.1/system-requirements/) one browser instance needs:

- 1 CPU core
- 2 GB of RAM

so for 500 browsers you will need at least 501 core and at least 1001 GB or RAM so most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Also as per [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) documentation:

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

Also as per [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

> Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

So I think you need to conduct the main load on HTTP protocol level and use 1-2 instances of real browser for frontend (client-side) performance testing.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri. We have a new data analytics tool integrated to our application. this will trigger an analytics even on some user actions like buttons clicks etc. I want to make sure this new implementation have no significant performance impact for users, when around 500 users access the application.